# Loaders do not execute task async

Tags: android, multithreading

It is the first time I'm using loaders. I'm using loaders to retrive the contact list of the phone.

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        String[] projection = { Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI };
        return new CursorLoader(this, Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    } else {
        String[] projection = { Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        return new CursorLoader(this, Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        //PARSE DATA
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

and in the `onCreate()` method I call

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

I get the contact list, but the loader executes the query in the main thread instead of in another thread, blocking the ui.

Any help please?

Comment: checkout this issue reported : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68013

Answer (score 0):

I would challenge your assertion that the query runs in the UI thread. The query runs in a background thread (onCreateLoader) and the cursor that results is returned to you on the UI thread (onLoadFinished), the intention being that you can use the results to update the UI in some manner, for example swapping the cursor into an adapter.

If you are doing a lot of work with the cursor in onLoadFinished, that is your own code blocking the UI, not the loader manager.